# Usage de la préposition "depuis" dans le sens spatial

Tags: usage, prépositions, synonymes, régionalismes

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/depuis/23940#difficulte

> Depuis employé pour de dans un sens spatial : je l'ai vu passer depuis ma fenêtre ; il m'écrit depuis son lieu de vacances. Emploi courant dans l'expression relâchée.
>
> Recommandation : Préférer de : je l'ai vu passer de ma fenêtre; il
> m'écrit de son lieu de vacances.
>
> Remarque : L'emploi de depuis dans un
> sens spatial est fréquent chez les journalistes de radio et de
> télévision (**calque de l'anglais from**) : en ligne notre envoyé spécial
> qui nous parle depuis Washington (au lieu de : de Washington).

Dans un commentaire sur Youtube j'ai lu :

> J'adore cette chanson. Merci pour la vidéo. Depuis Sénégal.

Cet emploi de depuis est-il régionalisme ? Est-il courant en France ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Depuis Sénégal* (sans article) est peut-être un régionalisme mais probablement plutôt une erreur.

L'expression attendue est *depuis **le** Sénégal*.

L'article est aussi requis dans l'expression que tu as écrite dans une autre question :

> Depuis **la** Russie avec amour.

Si ta question ne porte pas sur l'absence d'article mais sur l'utilisation de *depuis* à la place de *de* dans le sens spatial, oui, c'est un usage relativement courant en France.

On retrouve aussi un *depuis* non temporel dans des publicités où il est utilisé pour *à partir de*, par exemple :

> **Depuis** 15 €.